# Issue Related to Border-Radius in google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have follwing css class

```
form input[type="text"], form input[type="email"], form input[type="password"], form select, form textarea {
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    padding: 2px 0;
}
```

and following html and Java Script:

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" style="width:300px;" />
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="click here" class="medium required" onclick="return validate();"/>

<script language="javascript">
    function validate()
    {
         if (document.getElementById('txt1').value == '') {

            document.getElementById('txt1').style.borderLeft = "5px solid red";

            return false;
        }


    }
</script>
```

It works in Mozila but in google Chrome whenever validation fires inputbox gets css exctly applied in javascript but it also creates top and bottom border of 1px solid

how can i solve this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: i think it's a bug in chrome
with `border: 3px solid #CCCCCC;` the issue goes away but that's not nice !!

Comment: I don't observe this problem in the latest version of Chrome, Safari, or Firefox for OSX.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue, the top and bottom borders also turn red (in Chrome). You mention that they are 1px solid, but that is what you originally set them to in your css, so I assume the real issue is not that there is a solid 1px border but that it is the wrong color. So I assume they change from `#CCCCCC` to `red` when you only wanted the left border to do so.

I suspect that the `border-radius` (or the rendering of it after the fact) may be the issue. If you experiment with no `border-radius` does the issue still occur (I do not have access to Chrome to test myself)? If that solves it, then that is the problem. You might try overcoming it by doing something more explicit:

```
function validate()
    {
         var el = document.getElementById('txt1');
         if (el.value == '') {
            el.style.borderLeft = "5px solid red";
            el.style.borderTopColor = "#CCCCCC";
            el.style.borderBottomColor = "#CCCCCC";

            return false;
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**: Based on UnLoCo's information, both in his first comment here as well as his comment in your question, you might try not using the shorthand css and see if that solves it. So instead of your css having:

```
border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
```

You might try this in your base css and see if explicitly setting each border allows Chrome to not override the others when the left one is changed:

```
border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know (since I don't have Chrome to test). Can you tell me, is the issue that Chrome does make the top/bottom borders red? And does that effect go away if `border-radius` is not applied to the inputs?

Comment: yes the effect goes away with no radius.
here's a two cases that show the bug.

Comment: Thanks for the images. That is really weird that the red only shows up in the middle of the top/bottom border (I was expecting the whole thing to be red, not just a portion). It appears that the solution is to eliminate or change the border-radius or border-widths as you noted in your image.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug and has been reported: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=72120.

However, here is a workaround for your case:

Tweak the radius from all 3px to 3px / 1px. Though it's not perfect but somehow acceptable.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/linmic/VFBT3/51/